# String at the end of a text inside another string

Tags: php, string, formatting

I would like to use one string inside another string, like this:

> $url = "http://www.sample.com/index.php?nr=$string[0]";

how should I insert this string at the end?

Comment: $url = "http://www.sample.com/index.php?nr=".$string[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = "http://www.sample.com/index.php?nr={$string[0]}";
```

or

```
$url = "http://www.sample.com/index.php?nr=" . $string[0];
```

Comment: Single quotes should be used when the string does not contain variables.

Answer (score 0):

just like your example

```
$url = "http://www.sample.com/index.php?nr=$string[0]";
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please try executing following code snippet.

You need to concatenate strings in php using dot operator(.)

```
 $url = "http://www.sample.com/index.php?nr=".$string[0];
```